# Whats the best way to programatically open a pane inside Dijit AccordionContainer

Tags: accordion, dojo, accordionpane

I am trying open & close accordion panes programatically. Here is the simplified version of my code. Even though I set the first pane's selected to false and and second pane's selected to true, only the first pane opens when it loads on the browser (FF3).

```
var accordionContainer = new dijit.layout.AccordionContainer().placeAt("test");
var accordPane = new dijit.layout.ContentPane({"title": "test", "content":"hello"});
var accordPane2 = new dijit.layout.ContentPane({"title": "test1", "content":"hello1"});
accordionContainer.addChild(accordPane);
accordionContainer.addChild(accordPane2, 1);
accordPane.startup();
accordPane2.startup();
//accordionContainer.selectChild(accordPane2);
accordionContainer.startup();
accordPane.selected = false;
accordPane2.selected = true;
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
accordionContainer.selectChild( accordPane2 );
```

Assuming you are using dojo 1.3.

`dijit.layout.AccordionContainer` is a subclass of `dijit.layout.StackContainer`, which has `selectChild` defined.

I set up a [demo page where you can see this code in action](http://jsbin.com/elimo)

If you were calling `selectChild` before `startup`, that could cause the error you were seeing since the widget wasn't in a 'complete' state. (Sorry, missed the commneted out code before I posted original answer)

Comment: Thank you for responding.

I am using dojo 1.3.2. I tried doing 
    accordionContainer.selectChild( accordPane2 );
but it errored out. 
    newWidget._buttonWidget is undefined
According to the API doesn't look like selectChild is a function for AccordionContainer.