# How to switch AccordionPane on click?

Tags: arcgis, dojo

I have an app that uses dijit.layout.AccordionContainer with two "child containers"

When the map is loaded, one of the containers is open by default. I would like the default container to close and the second container to open when a button is clicked. Any idea how to do this?

I have tried using the selectChild() method but must be doing it wrong or am completely off base.

**EDIT**
My HTML is:

```
<div dojotype="dijit.layout.ContentPane" id="leftPane" region="left" splitter="true">
        <div dojotype="dijit.layout.AccordionContainer">
      <div dojotype="dijit.layout.ContentPane" title="Table of Contents">
                        <div id="tocDiv">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div dojotype="dijit.layout.ContentPane" title="Search Results" id="tab2">
                                                <div id="datagrid">
                                                <table data-dojo-type="dojox.grid.DataGrid" data-dojo-id="grid"  id="grid" data-dojo-props="rowsPerPage:'5', rowSelector:'20px'">
                                            <thead>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <th field="Parcel Identification Number" width="25%">
                            Parcel ID
                                                    </th>
                                                    <th field="Site Address" width="30%">
                            Address
                                                    </th>
                                                </tr>
                                            </thead>
                                        </table>
                                        </div>
                    </div>
        </div>
        </div>
```

where I am trying to open "tab2" on click via a function I have created for some other things I need to happen on click

JS:

```
function doFind() {             
        //Set the search text to the value in the box
        findParams.searchText = dojo.byId("parcel").value;
                grid.showMessage("Loading..."); //Shows the Loading Message until search results are returned.
        findTask.execute(findParams,showResults);
      }
```

Comment: This kind of pure JavaScript/Dojo Question is more suited to Stackoverflow, rather than Gis.Stackexchange.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are fairly close.

I am assuming you are listening to your own button click event. If you don't please post up that section of the code if you can.

If so then you need to do this:

```
<accordian-container>.selectChild( <pane to open>);
```

You need to pass the pane to the selectChild method.

The accordion container is a type of stack container so this documentation should help:

http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dijit/layout/StackContainer.html

Here is a link to almost the same question on Stackoverflow:  [Whats the best way to programatically open a pane inside Dijit AccordionContainer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1190157/whats-the-best-way-to-programatically-open-a-pane-inside-dijit-accordioncontaine)

Comment: Thanks. I have edited my question to show the code I am working with.