# XPages - Dojo Accordion Container with Panes

Tags: javascript, dojo, xpages, lotus-notes

On my XPage I have a Dojo Accordion Container with three Dojo Accordion Panes, each of which contains a Navigator. When I click on a Navigator Navigation Item, I would like to set the selectedTab property of the Dojo Accordion Container to the id of whichever Dojo Accordion Pane contains the Navigator whose Navigation Item has just been clicked. How can I best do this?

Comment: May be this answer would help: http://stackoverflow.com/q/16641668/1047998

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this issue using the tip from Naveen. When clicking on any item in a Dojo Accordion Pane the following code is executed:

```
var ac = dijit.byId("#{id:accordionContainer}");
ac.selectChild(dijit.byId("#{id:pane3}"));
```